# How to work with row index in T-Sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Table Reminder, Messaging and Users. I have to implement that whenever a row is created in the Reminder table then the Administrators from the Users table will get message in their Messaging table.

I am doing everything inside the sql query. I have reached till the inserton and selection of all admin users, also I am able to run a loop on the number of records. I want to insert one by one in a loop.

```
If @flag=1 // flag=1 means reminder is created successfully
BEGIN
 Declare @BackUpMessage as varchar(200)
 Set @BackupMessage = 'Hi Admin,\r\n
 \t A backup has been scheduled by the system. Details are given below: \r\n
    a) Bakcup Type : '+rem_type+' \r\n
    b) Backup Date : '+ Convert(varchar,GETDATE()+@days)+''
                    
 Set @Count = (Select Count(*) From JFPUsers Where RoleId=1 and Active=1) // Total Numbers of Admin
 IF @Count > 0
    Declare @i int =0

    Select Id From JFPUsers Where RoleId=1 and Active=1 // Getting Id of each admin to save
    While @i < @Count
    BEGIN
        Insert Into JFMessaging (MessageBody, SenderId,RecieverId,IsRead,SentOn,IsActive)
        Values(@BackUpMessage, -1, ,0,GETDATE(),1) // I am stucked here 
    END
END
```

I can do it easily using C# but I want to do these stuffs in a single connection and in a single hit @ backend .

**Update : See Image and the summary**

Summary : What I need is whenever a record is created in reminder. The query will pick all admin from JFPUsers {condition RoleId=1 is admin} and create that much row in JFMessaging where SenderId will be the user creating reminder or -1 (for system) and RecieverId will contain the admin id with a custom notification message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `INSERT` trigger on your Reminder table that does an INSERT into the messages table for administrators. Try to get out of the habit of using loops in SQL - it is usually bad practice.

Something like this...

```
insert JFMessaging (ReceiverID, Otherfields)
select UserID, otherfields
from
    inserted
        cross join
    JFPusers
where RoleID = 1
```

Comment: Oh!, you are right.It just slipped out from my mind. Thanks, It should do the trick

Comment: Wait a minute... Trigger will work for a single record. What If I have multiple inserts on a single insert???

Comment: @AmitRanjan A properly written trigger will work for multiple inserts quite happily.

Comment: hmmm... any sample query for the same...for my scenario

Comment: @AmitRanjan: a trigger in SQL Server is executed **once per batch** - so if you insert 50 rows at once, the trigger will fire **once** and the 50 rows will be available to you inside the trigger in the `Inserted` table (containing 50 rows, in that case). SQL Server triggers are **NOT** executed once per row

Comment: @marc_s : I understand the stuffs you presented here. What I want is quite different from what you are saying. You are saying that the 50 rows of the reminder table will be available inside the Inserted Table. But here i have nothing to do with the reminder table except the record keeping and event trigger , when to send notification. Thats all. I have to query the User table and save the message for each user in messaging table..

Comment: @AmitRanjan Yes - see the edit in the answer - the cross join will allow for one row to be inserted for each reminder for each administrator.

Comment: @podiluska : No sir, you still havent got my point. ANy ways thanks for the answer, i did it in C# part...